# Escape reserved keywords in object destructuring assignment

Tags: javascript, json, object-destructuring

Is it possible to use reserved keywords in an object destructuring assignment?

Specifically I am trying to handle JSON with property named default.

```
//Doesn't compile
class FooBar {
  constructor({foo, default}) {
    this.foo = foo;
    this.default = default;
  }
}
```

```
/* json from server {foo: "bar", default: true} */
new FooBar(json);
```

Comment: Seems like a better design to just not used reserved words since they're, y'know, reserved.

Comment: @Paul when working with vue + storybook, using the default keyword for slots is normal, and removing from the args is also quite useful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's possible to use them as a property name, but not as a variable name. Choose a different target:

```
class FooBar {
  constructor({foo, default: def}) {
    this.foo = foo;
    this.default = def;
  }
}
```

Comment: **It's possible to use them as a property name, but not as a variable name**, solved my problem. I now use destructuring this way: `const { get, list, delete: deleteHandler } = handlerObj;`