# How to correctly use a value returned by a promise and map through it

Tags: arrays, reactjs, promise

so I'm currently trying to return a value that I'm getting from a promise. The data returned is an array that I need to loop through it to get the correct value from a certain condition. Here is the code.

```
  const currency = await getCurrency().then(({ data }) => {

      data.map(({ default, code }) => {
        if (default){
        return code
      }
    })
  }
    return { pageProps, categories, currency };
  }
```

As asked, the getCurrency code

```
export const getCurrency = () => Moltin.Currencies.All();
```

I'm about 98% sure that my problem is coming from the syntax!
Thanks for the help

Comment: please add the code of `getCurrency()`

Comment: @Vencovsky I added the code.

Comment: Are you getting errors?

Comment: @Vencovsky Unexpected keyword 'default'

Comment: default is a reserved word in javascript, change the variable name.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52635676/escape-reserved-keywords-in-object-destructing-assignment) to see how to solve `Unexpected keyword 'default'`

Comment: @tutiplain That seems to have resolved the error !  The value is not showing (An other problem on my hand) but the error is gone. Thanks a lot for your help guys

Comment: I'm not sure what this function is supposed to do, but check what I wrote about the promises below. I think your other problem may be promise-related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some problems in your code

You can't use `default` because is a reserved keyword for javascript.
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52635733/9119186) answer to understand how to solve it.

In your case, you can do

```
  data.map(({ default: dev, code }) => {
    if (dev){
    return code
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If getCurrency() returns a promise, and you are using await, you do not need to use .then(). The variable called currency will hold the value returned from the promise.  .then() is only used in environments that don't support the async/await syntax.

Comment: getCurrency actually returns an array of data. I guess I'm not really getting a  promise? (my knowledge is pretty limited on that subject)

Comment: If a normal array is being returned then you don't need either await, not the .then()

Answer (score 0):

If you have a to get some values with some conditions, I would recommend you to use filter instead of map. map only transforms the data, and filter returns the elements based on the condition.

For example:

```
 const currency = await getCurrency().then(({ data }) => {

      data.filter(({ default, code }) => // some condition )
  }
    return { pageProps, categories, currency };
  }
```